# Is it possible to change post id for an already added menu item in Wordpress?

Tags: posts, menus, id

In Wordpress is it possible to change a post id of menu item (page) that was already added into a menu? Maybe via some custom function? Our menu is pretty big and i'm searching for an option to save some time via being able to change the post id instead of deleting the added menu item and re-add a new one with a different post id.

Thanks a bunch in advance!